# Using partial() to fix terms out of order

Tags: python, function, partial

Let's say I have a function:

```
def my_function(a, b, c):
    # Some Code
```

I can use:

```
functools.partial(my_function, "hello")
```

To get a callable of `my_function` where `a="hello"`. But suppose I want to set the value of parameter `b`. How could I set the value of parameter `b` without doing something like:

```
functools.partial(my_function, "hello", "bob")
```

which would also (undesirably) set the value of parameter `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do;

```
functools.partial(my_function, b='hello')
```

However you are going to have to specify your arguments with your parameter names coming after `b`:

```
>>> partial_function = functools.partial(my_function, b='hello')
>>> partial_function('a', c='c')
```

Comment: Well that was easy! Knew there had to be a simple way to do it.

Comment: Can't for four minutes